# Can't restore Bacpac from Azure to local SQL server - fails when creating Hangfire Schema

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, hangfire

Local SQL Server version: 2017 (v14.0.1000.169)
Remote Azure SQL server version: 12.0.2000.8
SQL Server Management Studio version: 14.0.17289.0 (v17.9.1)

Steps taken:

1. Export database from Azure SQL server using Tasks -> Export Data-tier Application (I have also tried excluding the Hangfire Schema)
2. Import database into Local SQL server using Tasks -> Import Data-tier Application

Getting this error:

> Could not import package.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [mydatabase20181127deploy_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [mydatabase20181127deploy_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Error SQL72014: SQL Execution error: A fatal error occurred. The variable HangFireSchema could not be found.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
>       CREATE SCHEMA [$(HangFireSchema)]
>           AUTHORIZATION [MyDatabase];
>
> Error SQL72014: SQL Execution error: A fatal error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered while CREATE SCHEMA [$(HangFireSchema)] was being parsed.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>       CREATE SCHEMA [$(HangFireSchema)]
>           AUTHORIZATION [MyDatabase];
>
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Comment: I have been able to remove the Hangfire schema and tables from the bacpac and generate a new checksum with http://inworksllc.com/editing-sql-database-azure-bacpac-files/ which imports okay, but is very tedious

Comment: Could you please use the export feature on Azure Portal? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export  Update SSMS to the latest version or use SqlPackage to import the bacpac generated on the portal

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo I have had the same issue - using the latest SSMS to export the bacpac results in the same error, as does trying to import the bacpac generated on the portal using the latest SSMS.